# Creating Android ArrayList Error

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am parsing the data from my XML file and putting it into an array, which then goes on to output it in another function.

```
private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
{
    ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();


    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    Animal currentAnimal = null;


    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {

        String name = null;
        switch (eventType)
        {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                //animals = new ArrayList();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase( "animal"))
                {
                    currentAnimal = new Animal();
                } 
                else if (currentAnimal != null)
                {
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase( "specificLocation"))
                    {
                        currentAnimal.specificLocation = parser.nextText();
                    } 
                    else if (name .equalsIgnoreCase( "name")){
                        currentAnimal.name = parser.nextText();
                    } 
                    else if (name .equalsIgnoreCase( "location"))
                    {
                        currentAnimal.location= parser.nextText();
                    }  
                    else if (name .equalsIgnoreCase( "image"))
                    {
                        currentAnimal.image= parser.nextText();
                    }  
                    else if (name .equalsIgnoreCase(  "animalInfo"))
                    {
                        currentAnimal.animalInfo= parser.nextText();
                    }  
                    else if (name .equalsIgnoreCase(  "todaysFeed"))
                    {
                        currentAnimal.todaysFeed= parser.nextText();
                    }  
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("animal") && currentAnimal != null){
                    animals.add(currentAnimal);
                } 
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }

    printAnimals(animals);
}
```

I'm getting an error at the line

```
animals.add(currentAnimal);
```

which tells me

> The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (AnimalList.Animal)

I originally had Animal instead of string, but I changed it as I couldn't output it, and I wasn't sure if that was why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you are trying to add the wrong type of object to the list.  You have defined the list as containing Strings, yet the object you are attempting to add is of type Animal.

You should define your list as containing Animal objects:

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

Comment: That's what I originally had but then

Comment: private void printAnimals(ArrayList<Animal> animals)
 {
  Animal[] animalArray = new Animal[animals.size()];
  animalArray = animals.toArray(animalArray);
  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAnimals);
  ArrayAdapter<Animal> animalAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Animal>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animals);
  listView.setAdapter(animalAdapter);
 } wouldn't work

Comment: Plus it is not clear what your current problem is.  Are you trying to fix a compilation error, or is something else wrong?

Comment: Actually, I understand, I thought I had to use String rather than my own defined, but if I can use animal then your solution works for me